# python-social-auth and Django, replace UserSocialAuth with custom model

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-social-auth

I'm trying to integrate [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) into an existent Django project.

I want to use an existent model for a user's social accounts, instead of UserSocialAuth (my DB already has data with it, as well as some custom fields).

Is there some setting for it?

My custom model looks like this:

```
class Channel(models.Model, DjangoUserMixin):
    PROVIDER_CHOICES = (
        ('twitter', 'Twitter'),
    )

    uid = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True,
                             related_name='channels')

    provider = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=PROVIDER_CHOICES)
    extra_data = JSONField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('provider', 'uid')

    @classmethod
    def get_social_auth(cls, provider, uid):
        try:
            return cls.objects.select_related('user').get(provider=provider, uid=uid)
        except Channel.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    username_max_length = 255
    user_model = get_user_model()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I opened up a ticket to support extending the ``UserSocialAuth`` model.  You shouldn't have to copy/paste all the existing ``UserSocialAuth`` model in your new model.  It should be an abstract class that can be extended.  That way you could add whatever new fields you wanted while leveraging the existing model: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/698

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by creating a custom `Storage`:

```
# channels/models.py
# ...

class CustomSocialStorage(DjangoStorage):
    """To replace UserSocialAuth model with Channel"""
    user = Channel
```

And registering it in the settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_STORAGE = 'proj.channels.models.CustomSocialStorage'
```

For some reason this setting is documented only in the ["Django" section](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/django.html?highlight=social_auth_storage) of Python-social-auth's documentation, and not on the Settings page.